# Windows USB media crashes

Tags: windows-10, boot, crash, windows-installation

I recently switched to a SSD. It worked fine as long as I manually selected the boot drive.

Then I deleted everything on the original HDD(it is still installed for bulk storage) and now it won't boot, so it must have been still using something from that HDD.

I created a windows 10 installation USB drive on another PC, and it crashes as soon as I boot to it. Any ideas?

Here is a pic of what happens when it crashes:

[image]

**UPDATE**: I think I figured out why windows media wasn't booting, it works as long as I boot in legacy. But is there some way I can just replace the BCD file without reinstalling? That's what is missing btw.
here is what happens when I try to boot to the SSD.

[image]

**UPDATE**: I have tried a few different tutorials for rebuilding BCD and none of them worked so I guess I will just reinstall windows. But I can't figure out how to reinstall without deleting files if the PC wont boot? So how would I go about doing it? The USB drive made with the media creation tool doesn't seem to allow it.

Comment: What did you do to switch to an SSD?

Comment: I used Acronis to clone the drive.

Comment: It is possible to convert from legacy to UEFI boot, and it is quite easy with MBR2GPT and the appropriate setting change in the "BIOS", but you probably want a separate backup of your SSD first - do you have a spare drive you can create the backup on? Or at least a backup of everything you want to keep, just in case something goes wrong?

Comment: No my HDD is UEFI, but the USB drive only boots in legacy.

Comment: @Randomaker - You will have to recreate your installation media.  What tool did you use to create it? "Is there some way I can just replace the BCD file without reinstalling?" - You will have to be more specific

Comment: I already recreated the media a few times, I used the tool from windows. What I meant was do I have to fully reinstall windows or can I just replace the missing file, but I tried to follow a few tutorials and none of them worked to at this point I'm just trying to figure out how to reinstall windows without loosing files. Do I need to select make iso file and then put that on the flash drive instead of directly creating the media with the windows media creation tool?